# Dropdown menu from table showing two columns e.g. subid - subcategory in the dropdown list

Tags: php, dropdown

Hi I got this dropdown from a table that works.

```
   $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
require "configure.php";
$q=mysql_query("select * from arbejdsopgave where cat_id='$cat_id' and status2!='lukket'");
echo mysql_error();
$myarray=array();
$str="";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$str=$str . "\"$nt[subcategory]\"".",";
}
$str=substr($str,0,(strLen($str)-1)); // Removing the last char , from the string
echo "new Array($str)";
```

However I would like to add a column to the string that is showed in the dropdown from the column "sub_id" so that the dropdown shows 
sub_id - subcategory. E.g:

673 - new roof instead of the current that only shows new roof.

I tried combining a string as below but the result was first the subcategory then followed by the subid in the list e.g. 
subcat1
subcat2
subcat3
1
2
3

```
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
require "config.php";
$q=mysql_query("select * from arbejdsopgave where cat_id='$cat_id' and status2!='lukket'");
echo mysql_error();
$myarray=array();
$str="";
$subid="";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$str=$str . "\"$nt[subcategory]\"".",";
$subid=$subid . "\"$nt[sub_id]\"".",";
$str2=$str." ".$subid;
}
$str2=substr($str2,0,(strLen($str2)-1)); // Removing the last char , from the string
echo "new Array($str2)";
```

Hope you can help me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MYSQL as a backend then just use query to concat the result as below.

```
select CONCAT('sub_id ', 'subcategory') as category,othercolumnnames from arbejdsopgave where cat_id='$cat_id' 
and status2!='lukket';
```